# JPanel GridBagLayout not aligning vertical objects

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, gridbaglayout

The problem with the following code is that it is splitting the `MenuPane` in half instead of the desired 10% to 90%

`TitlePane` and `ControlPane` are just JPanels.

```
public class MenuPane extends JPanel {

public MenuPane( int width, int height ){

    setSize( width, height );

    setLayout( new GridBagLayout() );

    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;

    c.weightx = 0.0d;
    c.weighty = 0.1d;

    add( new TitlePane( this.getWidth(), (int) (this.getHeight()*c.weighty) ), c );


    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 1;

    c.weightx = 0.0d;
    c.weighty = 0.9d;

    add( new ControlPane( this.getWidth(), (int) (this.getHeight()*c.weighty) ), c );

}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
add( new TitlePane( this.getWidth(), (int) (this.getHeight()*c.weighty) ), c );
```

Don't really know what that code does, but components don't have a size until the component is displayed on a visible GUI. So your getWidth()/Height() methods will return 0.

If you want components to be displayed in a 90/10 ratio then the initial preferred size must also be in a 90/10 ratio. The weighty factor only applies when a component is resized.

I don't know what your ControlPane code looks like so I can't suggest a specific change to make.

You could try using the [Relative Layout](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/02/relative-layout/) which was designed specifically for this. You just need to specify the ration when you add the components to the container and it will manage the size from there.